# Android Studio can not access android sdk

Tags: android, batch-file

I have installed android bundle for windows . I have also installed jdk 1.8 and set necessary environment variables.But when it opens and i try to create a project and click on tools->android sdk manager it shows the following error message:

Gradle build finished in 2 min 2 sec
2:52:43 PM ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "C:\androidnewsdk\tools\android.bat":  Access is denied

i have already run it as administrator. i wanted to check what the problem was going to the sdk folder and clicked on sdk manager .it shows error message:

failed to execute tools\android.batch
the system cannot find the file specified.

PS. 1.temp folder in sdk is empty(might be a problem)

2.No error was shown during installation or update

3. I am running windows 8.1 64bit.(jdk is for 64 bit)

what is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variable JAVA_HOME for jdk 1.8 .
Also have you set the jdk and sdk paths in Android Studio? Try doing that in File>Project Structure.

hope it helps

Comment: Its not the sdk manager. The project structure is under file tab.

Comment: Set the JAVA_HOME variable in my computer>properties>advance system  settings>environment variables. click edit in the top window and give JAVA_HOME for variable and paste your jdk path for value

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved the problem...
I had already set JAVA_HOME variable and other necessary things, but it was not working for some reason. Then i reinstalled windows and followed same installation procedures again, but this time everything worked just fine.